# SparkPost sending emails

Tags: java, android, sparkpost

I'm trying to use Html tags for sending emails just like designing template, how can i do it.

Using sendEmail method of sparkLibrary i can send only text formatted emails, how can i design templates for the email and send it.

```
 SparkPostEmailUtil.sendEmail(MainActivity.this,
                etSparkPostApiKey.getText().toString(),
                etSubject.getText().toString(),
                etContent.getText().toString(),
                new SparkPostSender(etSenderEmail.getText().toString(), getString(R.string.app_name)),
                new SparkPostRecipient(etRecipientEmail.getText().toString()),
                new EmailListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {
                        if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                        builder.setTitle("Success")
                                .setMessage("Email has been sent successfully.")
                                .show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(String errorMessage) {
                        if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                        builder.setTitle("Error Sending Email")
                                .setMessage(errorMessage)
                                .show();
                        Log.e(TAG, "Error sending SparkPost email: " + errorMessage);
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

I *think* you're using `android-sparkpost` [from here](https://github.com/NoelChew/android-sparkpost) which looks great for quickly sending a message. To use SparkPost's template capabilities though, you'll likely need direct access the transmissions REST API endpoint.

You could use the `java-sparkpost` client [here](https://github.com/SparkPost/java-sparkpost) to help with that. [Here's an example of sending a transmission](https://github.com/SparkPost/java-sparkpost/blob/master/apps/sparkpost-samples-app/src/main/java/com/sparkpost/samples/SendEmailWithSubstitutionSample.java) using `java-sparkpost`.

To use a stored template:

1. [Create your template on your account here](https://app.sparkpost.com/templates)
2. Note the ID of your template
3. Send a transmission with the template ID (`templateId`) set to your chosen template. Something like this:

   `TemplateContentAttributes contentAttributes = new TemplateContentAttributes();
   contentAttributes.setTemplateId("your-template-id");
   transmission.setContentAttributes(contentAttributes);`